# How to find the longest common prefix of two strings in Scala?

Tags: string, scala, list-comprehension

How to find the longest common prefix of two strings in Scala?

I probably can code an "imperative" solution (with an index `i` running over the strings while `s(i) == t(i)`) but I am looking for a "functional-style" solution (without updating the index variable explicitly, for instance).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
scala> "helloworld".zip("hellohell").takeWhile(Function.tupled(_ == _)).map(_._1).mkString
res130: String = hello
```

Comment: Using `.unzip._1` instead of `.map(_._1)` arguably makes what's going on a little clearer.

Comment: It's a bit of a waste to zip the entire strings, when the common prefix may be just a few chars

Comment: If you change `"helloworld".zip("hellohell")` to `("helloworld", "hellohell").zipped`, I think that takes care of the inefficiency.

Comment: @DavidY.Ross: +1. Or `"helloworld".view zip "hellohell"`.

Comment: I'd suggest using `takeWhile { case (a, b) => a == b }` instead of `takeWhile(Function.tupled(_ == _))`.

Comment: @XavierGuihot, sure. I think it's a stylistic preference.

Answer (score 7):

Another recursive version.

```
def pref(s: String, t: String, out: String = ""): String = {
  if (s == "" || t == "" || s(0) != t(0)) out
  else pref(s.substring(1), t.substring(1), out + s(0))
}
```

It's over 10 times quicker than sjj's and over twice as fast as missingfaktor's. Java's `substring` is fast because `String` is immutable.

Answer (score 3):

Recursive version:

```
def findCommonPrefix(s1 : String, s2 : String) : String = {
    def findCommonPrefixR(l1: List[Char], l2 : List[Char]) : List[Char] = {
        l1 match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case x::xs => if (l2 != Nil && l2.head == x) x :: findCommonPrefixR(xs, l2.tail) else Nil
        }
    }
    findCommonPrefixR(s1.toList, s2.toList).mkString
}
```

Comment: Luigi mentions this his is over 10 times quicker than mine.  It actually depends.  With strings that don't have many match characters, his is quicker.  However, for strings that are likely to have more characters that match, mine is actually > 2x the speed of his.

Comment: Luigi, try timing this: pref("this is a a string that is somewhat, moderately, sort of long in length", "this is a a string that is somewhat, moderately, sort of long in length")

Comment: I admit I only did a very quick and un-thorough benchmark with a single test string. The performance of yours improves a lot when run an a 64-bit JVM. As missingfaktor's imperative version shows, both are still very inefficient in terms of machine operations.

Answer (score 2):

The imperative version can be simplified to

```
def longestCommonPrefix(s1:String, s2:String):String = {
  val maxSize = scala.math.min(s1.length, s2.length)
  var i:Int = 0;
  while ( i < maxSize && s1(i)== s2(i)) i += 1;
  s1.take(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If speed is the deal, go imperative.

```
scala> def longestCommonPrefix(a: String, b: String): String = {
     |   var same = true
     |   val sb = new StringBuilder
     |   var i = 0
     |   while(same && i < math.min(a.length, b.length)) {
     |     if(a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
     |       same = false
     |     } else {
     |       sb += a.charAt(i)
     |       i += 1
     |     }
     |   }
     |   sb.result
     | }
longestCommonPrefix: (a: String, b: String)String

scala> longestCommonPrefix("", "")
res50: String = ""

scala> longestCommonPrefix("helloworld", "hellohell")
res51: String = hello
```

EDIT:

As per Luigi's suggestion:

```
scala> def longestCommonPrefix(a: String, b: String): String = {
     |   var same = true
     |   var i = 0
     |   while(same && i < math.min(a.length, b.length)) {
     |     if(a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
     |       same = false
     |     } else {
     |       i += 1
     |     }
     |   }
     |   a.substring(0, i)
     | }
longestCommonPrefix: (a: String, b: String)String

scala> longestCommonPrefix("helloworld", "hellohell")
res68: String = hello
```

Comment: Instead of using a StringBuilder just count the index, then return `a.substring(0, i)`. This is much faster because you don't have to build a new String at all.

Answer (score 0):

To get the common prefix of any number of strings:

```
def commonPrefix (strs: Seq[String]): String = {
  var i = 0;
  strs(0).takeWhile { ch => strs.forall(_(i) == ch) && {i += 1; true}} mkString
}
```

Comment: not quite... it'll fail with an overflow. You need to check against the length of the shortest string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def commonPrefix(strings: String*): String = {
  val refString = strings.map(s => (s, s.length())).minBy { case (string, length) => length }._1
  var i = 0
  while (i < refString.length) {
    if (!strings.forall(_(i) == refString(i))) return refString.substring(0, i)
    i += 1
  }
  return refString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per OP request, below is a simple optimally fast Functional-Style implementation.

This implementation is as fast as any handwritten mutable imperative style (because it is tail recursive).

```
def takeCommonPrefix(string1: String, string2: String): String = {
  if (string1.nonEmpty && string2.nonEmpty) {
    val (shorter, longer) =
      if (string1.length < string2.length) (string1, string2)
      else (string2, string1)

    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recursive(shorterIndex: Int = 0): String =
      if (shorterIndex == shorter.length)
        shorter
      else
        if (shorter(shorterIndex) != longer(shorterIndex))
          shorter.take(shorterIndex)
        else
          recursive(shorterIndex + 1)

    recursive()
  }
  else
    ""
}
```

As a bonus, if you wanted the common prefix, there's a fairly good chance the need for the common suffix is just around the corner.

```
  def takeCommonSuffix(string1: String, string2: String): String = {
    if (string1.nonEmpty && string2.nonEmpty) {
      val (shorter, longer) =
        if (string1.length < string2.length) (string1, string2)
        else (string2, string1)
      val longerOffset =
        longer.length - shorter.length

      @scala.annotation.tailrec
      def recursive(shorterIndex: Int = shorter.length - 1): String =
        if (shorterIndex == -1)
          shorter
        else
          if (shorter(shorterIndex) != longer(shorterIndex + longerOffset))
            shorter.takeRight(shorter.length - shorterIndex - 1)
          else
            recursive(shorterIndex - 1)

      recursive()
    }
    else
      ""
  }
```